# Parse/Read XML from a specific folder(path)

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, path

How can I parse all the xml files from a specific folder ?

For example I have 'orders' folder created in the application folder.

I want to read all those xml files from the folder.

If I put the xml files in the 'root' folder (application folder), a 'for' loop is doing the job. But how can I change the path ?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        File folder = new File("orders/");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        String fileName = null;
        for (int im = 0; im < listOfFiles.length; im++) {
            if (listOfFiles[im].isFile()) {
                fileName = listOfFiles[im].getName();

                Document doc = builder.parse(fileName);
```

Here is a part of my code. 'File folder' should the path. But it is just reading those files, I can printing out, but is not parsing them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you have to parse the file not the fileName.

use something like this:

```
    File folder = new File("orders/");
    for(File workfile : folder.listFiles()){
        if(workfile.isFile()){
            Document doc = builder.parse(workfile);
        }
    }
```